# Modificar un atributo de un objeto en una lista y que no se modifique en las demas listas

Tags: java, lista, poo, arraylist

Tengo varias listas que comparten objetos, y necesito modificar un atributo de un objeto, solo en una lista, sin que se afecte en las demas.
Este es el codigo en Main:

```
     //Creo 3 objedos de Alumno
 Alumno Alumno1 = new Alumno();
 Alumno1.setNombre("Luis");
 Alumno1.setEdad(32);
 Alumno Alumno2 = new Alumno();
 Alumno2.setNombre("Fernando");
 Alumno2.setEdad(28);
 Alumno Alumno3 = new Alumno();
 Alumno3.setNombre("Andrea");
 Alumno3.setEdad(30);

     //creo 3 listas de asignaturas para cada alumno
 List<Asignatura> listaAsignaturas1 = new ArrayList<Asignatura> ();
 List<Asignatura> listaAsignaturas2 = new ArrayList<Asignatura>();
 List<Asignatura> listaAsignaturas3 = new ArrayList<Asignatura>();

     //Le asigno a cada alumno una lista
 Alumno1.setListaAsignaturas(listaAsignaturas1);
 Alumno2.setListaAsignaturas(listaAsignaturas2);
 Alumno3.setListaAsignaturas(listaAsignaturas3);

//creo objetos de Asignatura
 Asignatura Calculo = new Asignatura("Calculo");
 Asignatura LPOO = new Asignatura("LPOO");
 Asignatura Fisica = new Asignatura("Fisica");
 Asignatura Comunicaciones = new Asignatura("Comunicaciones");
 Asignatura Matematicas = new Asignatura("Matematicas");
 Asignatura BaseDeDatos = new Asignatura("Base de datos");
 Asignatura Logica = new Asignatura("Logica de programacion");

     //Asigno Asignaturas a las listas
 listaAsignaturas1.add(Calculo);
 listaAsignaturas1.add(Fisica);
 listaAsignaturas1.add(Matematicas);
 
 listaAsignaturas2.add(LPOO);
 listaAsignaturas2.add(BaseDeDatos);
 listaAsignaturas2.add(Matematicas);
 listaAsignaturas2.add(Logica);
 
 listaAsignaturas3.add(Comunicaciones);
 listaAsignaturas3.add(Calculo);
 listaAsignaturas3.add(Fisica);
 listaAsignaturas3.add(LPOO);
 
 listaAsignaturas1.get(1).setNota(3);
 listaAsignaturas3.get(2).setNota(4);
```

Al imprimir las listas, la asignatura a la que le estoy "setiando" la nota me imprime con la ultima nota dada.
Es posible asignar una nota diferente en cada lista, asi sea el mismo objeto?
Gracias.

Comment: por lo que mencionas pareciera que tienes los atributos de tus clases como static , lo cual debes borrar....

Comment: @Dramaturgo hola. No, de hecho los tenía así, los cambié y nada.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que estás utilizando los mismos objetos en una lista y otra. Cuando hacés

```java
 //creo objetos de Asignatura
 Asignatura Calculo = new Asignatura("Calculo");
 Asignatura LPOO = new Asignatura("LPOO");
 Asignatura Fisica = new Asignatura("Fisica");
 Asignatura Comunicaciones = new Asignatura("Comunicaciones");
 Asignatura Matematicas = new Asignatura("Matematicas");
 Asignatura BaseDeDatos = new Asignatura("Base de datos");
 Asignatura Logica = new Asignatura("Logica de programacion");
```

y luego

```java
listaAsignaturas1.add(Calculo);
listaAsignaturas3.add(Calculo);
```

Tanto `listaAsignaturas1` como `listaAsignaturas3` contienen "el mismo elemento".

Esto se debe a que al hacer

```java
ElNombreDeLaClase elNombreDelObjecto = new ElNombreDeLaClase();
```

Lo que estás haciendo es que `elNombreDelObjecto` contenga una referencia a una instancia de `ElNombreDeLaClase`. Por lo que si tenés otra clase que guarde esa referencia, ya sea una `List` o una clase que vos creaste, cada vez que invoquen un método que altere el estado interno de la misma (es decir, cambie un valor de un atributo) se va a estar ocurriendo "en ambos lados" porque todos están apuntando al mismo objeto en realidad.

```java
ElNombreDeLaClase elNombreDelObjecto = new ElNombreDeLaClase();
ElNombreDeLaClase elNombreDelObjectoReferenciado = elNombreDelObjecto; // haciendo esto, asigno la referencia del primero en el nuevo objecto declarado

elNombreDelObjecto.setAtributo(algunValor); // afecto estado interno del primero
elNombreDelObjectoReferenciado.setAtributo(ultimoValorAsginado); // afecto estado interno del primero, ya que éste tiene la referencia a `elNombreDelObjecto`
elNombreDelObjecto.getAtributo(); // voy a obtener como valor `ultimoValorAsginado` por más que esté llamando a `elNombreDelObjecto` y le haya invocado el método `setAtributo` con un valor distinto previamente
```

lo mismo te está pasando con el `ArrayList` al hacerle `add`. Lo que deberías hacer es crear una nueva instancia de `Asignatura` para no tener ese problema.

Answer (score 0):

En realidad no es viable hacerlo de esa manera, cada alumno debe tener sus propias asignaturas (también lo puedes hacer a la inversa, que cada asignatura tenga una lista de alumnos, pero se me hace poco claro).
Como estoy muy atrevido, me permití hacer unas modificaciones...

La clase **Asignatura** no requiere mayores comentarios...

```
public class Asignatura {
   String nombre;
   List<Double> notas;

   public Asignatura( String nom ) {
      nombre = nom;
      notas = new ArrayList<>();
   }

   public void setNota( double nota ) {
      notas.add( nota );
   }

   public List<Double> getNotas() {
      return notas;
   }

   public double getUltimaNota() {
      return notas.get( notas.size() -1 );
   }

   //  el método sobre-escrito
   @Override
   public String toString() {
      return "Asignatura{ Nombre: " + nombre + " nota: " + notas + "}";
   }
}
```

La clase **Alumno** tiene una pequeña modificación, cambié la lista de asignaturas por un **Map**, de esta forma, puedo llamar a una asignatura por su nombre.

```
public class Alumno {
   Map<String, Asignatura> listaAsignaturas;
   String nombre;

      // sería más lógico es que reciba un objeto Persona
   public Alumno( String nomb ) {  
      nombre = nomb;
   }    
  
   public Map<String, Asignatura> getListaAsignaturas() {
      return listaAsignaturas;
   }  

   public void setNuevaAsignatura( String nombre, Asignatura asignatura ) {
      listaAsignaturas.put( nombre, asignatura );
   }      
}

void main() {
     // para faciltar el trabajo uso array's con los nombres y las asignaturas básicas
   String nombresAlumnos[] = { "Luis", "Fernando", "Andrea" };
   String listadoAsignaturasBasicas[] = { "Matematicas", "Fisica", "Calculo" };

      // cambio "List" por "Map" para llamar al alumno por su nombre
   Map<String, Alumno> listaAlumnos = new HashMap<>();
   for( int i = 0; i < nombresAlumnos.length; i++ ) {
      String nombre = nombresAlumnos[ i ];
         // agrego a la lista de alumnos, una "key" (su nombre) y el objeto "Alumno"
      listaAlumnos.put( nombre, new Alumno( nombre ));

         // traigo el "Map" de asignaturas del alumno y le agrego las asignaturas básicas
      Map<String, Asignatura> listaAsignaturas1 = listaAlumnos.get( nombre ).getListaAsignaturas();
      for( int j = 0; j < listadoAsignaturasBasicas.length; j++ ) {
         listaAsignaturas1.put( listadoAsignaturasBasicas[ j ], new Asignatura( listadoAsignaturasBasicas[ j ] ) );
      }
   }

      // usamos...
   String nuevaAsignatura = "Algebra";
   listaAlumnos.get( "Luis" ).getListaAsignaturas().put( nuevaAsignatura, new Asignatura( nuevaAsignatura ));
   Alumno A = listaAlumnos.get( "Luis" );
   A.getListaAsignaturas().get( "Algebra" ).setNota( 7.9 );
   double nota = listaAlumnos.get( "Luis" ).getListaAsignaturas().get( "Algebra" ).getUltimaNota();
   System.out.println( nota );
}
```

No espero que sea el mejor camino, es solo una forma de llegar a "Roma".

Haciendome eco de tu comentario, agrego dos formas, de llegar a "Roma"...

```
public class Alumno {

   List<Asignatura> listaAsignaturas = new ArrayList<>();
   String nombre;
   int edad;
   // los getter's y los setter's
}
```

Un método auxiliar que le pide al alumno recibido como parámetro,
su lista de asignaturas y agrega las asignaturas que crea a la misma

```
void agregarAsignaturas( Alumno alumno ) {
   List<Asignatura> listaAsignaturas = alumno.getListaAsignaturas();
   listaAsignaturas.add( new Asignatura( "Calculo" ) );
   listaAsignaturas.add( new Asignatura( "LPOO" ) );
   listaAsignaturas.add( new Asignatura( "Fisica" ) );
   listaAsignaturas.add( new Asignatura( "Comunicaciones" ) );
   listaAsignaturas.add( new Asignatura( "Matematicas" ) );
   listaAsignaturas.add( new Asignatura( "Base de datos" ) );
   listaAsignaturas.add( new Asignatura( "Logica de programacion" ) );
}


void main() {
   Alumno alumno1 = new Alumno();
   alumno1.setNombre( "Luis" );
   alumno1.setEdad( 32 );
   agregarAsignaturas( alumno1 );

      // la siguiente lista puedo o no, existir, si existe, cambiamos 
      // "alumno1" por "listaAlumnos.get( numeroDeOrden )".
   List<Alumno> listaAlumnos = new ArrayList<>();
   listaAlumnos.add( alumno1 );

      // usando --- 
      // primero paso a paso
      // le pedimos al alumno su lista de asignaturas  
   List<Asignatura> listaAsignaturas = alumno1.getListaAsignaturas();

      // a la lista le pedimos una signatura en particular
   Asignatura asignatura = listaAsignaturas.get( 0 );
   
      // agregamos a la asignatura una nota
   asignatura.setNota( 7.9 );

      // podemos hacer todo en una linea
   alumno1.getListaAsignaturas().get( 0 ).setNota( 7.9 );

      // pedimos una nota
   double nota = alumno1.getListaAsignaturas().get( 0 ).getUltimaNota();

      // agregamos una asignatura
   alumno1.getListaAsignaturas().add( new Asignatura( "Algebra" ));
   System.out.println( nota );
   System.out.println( alumno1.getListaAsignaturas() );
}

Este es otro enfoque, que hace más sencillo la utilización, pero tiene como contra, que no se pueden agregar o quitar asignaturas.

public class Alumno {

   Asignatura Calculo = new Asignatura( "Calculo" );
   Asignatura LPOO = new Asignatura( "LPOO" );
   Asignatura Fisica = new Asignatura( "Fisica" );
   Asignatura Comunicaciones = new Asignatura( "Comunicaciones" );
   Asignatura Matematicas = new Asignatura( "Matematicas" );
   Asignatura BaseDeDatos = new Asignatura( "Base de datos" );
   Asignatura Logica = new Asignatura( "Logica de programacion" );
   String nombre;
   int edad;

   public Asignatura getCalculo() {
      return Calculo;
   }

   public Asignatura getLPOO() {
      return LPOO;
   }

   public Asignatura getFisica() {
      return Fisica;
   }

   public Asignatura getComunicaciones() {
      return Comunicaciones;
   }

   public Asignatura getMatematicas() {
      return Matematicas;
   }

   public Asignatura getBaseDeDatos() {
      return BaseDeDatos;
   }

   public Asignatura getLogica() {
      return Logica;
   }

   public void setNombre( String nombre ) {
      this.nombre = nombre;
   }

   public void setEdad( int edad ) {
      this.edad = edad;
   }

}


void main() {
   Alumno alumno1 = new Alumno();
   alumno1.setNombre( "Luis" );
   alumno1.setEdad( 32 );

   // usamos ---
   alumno1.getCalculo().setNota( 7.9 );
   double nota = alumno1.getCalculo().getUltimaNota();
   System.out.println( nota );
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, pero creo que esta muy elevado para mi nivel, voy a revisarla, estudiarla y guardarla e intentare realizar el ejercicio de otra manera. Gracias

Comment: Hola Marce, te comparto la manera en q termine el código. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda. https://github.com/LFPena91/Actividad2.2.1  decidí no intentar lo de los maps xq no los manejo muy bien, creo q depronto me quedó un poquito largo, pero ahí voy. Gracias

Comment: en **Estudiante**, tenes **private String materia1;**, tiene que ser una **Asignatura**, ya que a un String no le podes pedir la "nota", esto te obliga a cambiar la forma en que creas la asignatura, por otro lado, al no usar una lista de asignaturas, tenes que limitarte a tener una cantidad de atributos tan grande como la cantidad de asignaturas existentes (declaraste solo dos) lo que no me parece adecuado,

Comment: en **Asignatura** tenes **private static double nota;**, no es que este mal, no parece un escenario realista, solo puede tener una nota, por eso yo puse un LIst de notas, aparte tenes **public static Object asignatura() {** que devuelve **null** antes debería devolver un String, corrigiendo debe devolver una asignatura ya instanciada.